# SharePoint 2007 Workflow to insert the content of attachment of a InfoPath form into the email

Tags: workflow, 2007, infopath, pdf, jpg

I have an InfoPath 2007 form that has 2 attachment field for people to upload any of the following types of files: `PDF`, `DOC`, `DOCX`, `JPG`, `GIF`, `BMP`.

If the end-user submit any of above types of files as an attachment on the InfoPath 2007 form and clicked submit, it will trigger a workflow that sends out an email which also contains the contents of the attachment.

So, my question is: how do one make the workflow insert the content (not the filename) of the attachment to the email such that when the end-user open the email, it will see the attachment content rather than as an attachment? (meaning that for example, if the attachment is a `BMP` and a `DOCX` file, it will display both files in the email's body field rather than as an attachment for end-user to download it.)